# Standalone file with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

I developed a python script along with PySimpleGUI. Now I am trying to convert it to a standalone file but when I create the EXE file with PyInstaller, the executable just does not work. I doubleclick and nothing appears. I believe there is something wrong in my py file that makes the PySimpleGUI window not showing up.
So here is the part of my code:

```
sg.theme('DarkTeal9')
ttk_style = ''

layout =   [
        [sg.T(ttk_style)],
        [sg.Text('APP', font=("Calibri", 20))],
    
        [sg.Text('   ')],

        [sg.Text('Fichero ARC Laurea:'), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
        [sg.Text('Fichero Oferta Laurea:'), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
        [sg.Text('Fichero Nóminas:'), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
        [sg.Button('Procesar',bind_return_key=True,use_ttk_buttons=True)],
        [sg.Text('Ventana de progreso:')],
        [sg.Output(size=(75,25),key='inputbox')],
        [sg.Text('   ')]]
                    
iconpath=\somepathtoimage

window = sg.Window('myapp',icon=iconpath, ttk_theme=ttk_style).Layout(layout)



while True: 
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break
        
    if event == 'Procesar':
        arc_ruta=values[0]
        propuestas_ruta=values[1]
        nominas_ruta=values[2]

        generar_propuestas(arc_ruta, propuestas_ruta, nominas_ruta) #calling the function

    elif event == 'Process':
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xlsx')):
            with open(filename,'rb') as f:
                pdf = f.read()
            
    
window.close()




function()
```

Comment: As suggested by @Idontknowsohelpme, try to launch your executable from terminal to be able to see any error messages. Please post the error message together with your question. Knowing the error makes it much easier to (help you to) solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the files , you can see the error if you open your exe from CMD , open a CMD where your exe is and "./yourapp.exe"

Also you would have to enable debuging mode , you can make those changes in your .spec file for pyinstaller

here is my sample:

```
import sys
import os

path = os.path.abspath(".")

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['F:\\path\\to\\your\\main.py'],
             pathex=['F:\\path\\to\\project'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('F:\\path\\to\\folder\\dataneeded','.'),
                    ('F:\\path\\to\\folder\\dataneeded\\*.png','.\\dataneeded'),
                    ('F:\\path\\to\\folder\\dataneeded\\*.ico','.\\dataneeded')
                    ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False
             )
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          [],
          name='Appname',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('F:\\path\\to\\project'),
               a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,   
               name='Appname')
```

You will have to add all the file you need in data as shown above
for example you have a folder with images
first you set the folder and then you set the type of file it has to put in folder